# Getting .py scripts to open up in Python's IDLE

Tags: windows, python, file-association

I'm new to Python. I use Python 2.7 and I am running Windows Vista (64-bit). How do I make it when I click on .py scripts... that it opens up in IDLE so I can edit it a snap? Ya know... without having to open IDLE by itself. Heh.

I got all the way to `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib` but I don't see the IDLE application.

Then when I do right-click and "Default open with" and select the `idle.bat` file.. I get this: [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply right clicking the script and selecting `Edit with IDLE`?

Comment: I do not have that.

Comment: Ok, brainwave: try selecting pythonw.exe from the installed programs when the error window you posted pops up.

Comment: OK I did that... and nothing happened... it's like I never even selected even though I FOUND IT.. and pressed OK on pythonw.exe... Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Go to folder options.
Click File Types.
Click New.
Give the extension i.e py and click OK.
Under opens with, click Change button.
Click Browse and select the idle.bat from the location.

This will associate idle to open py files.

This link might be helpful for Vista.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2127/vista_associate_file_type_program/#

Comment: Where is IDLE located at? Also I am at Vista.. I do not see File Types in my Folder Options...

Comment: I'm sorry. They have removed the File Types tab from folder options. The above link might be helpful.

Comment: You can find it in Start/Default Programs.

Comment: I get: "Windows cannot find 'idle.pyw'

Answer (score 1):

Delete theses keys from the registry and do repair-install from the MSI.

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.PY`

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py`

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10:

Type "Default Programs" in the start menu. "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program". Select ".py". Click "Change Program". Choose "Python Launcher for Windows". This worked for me even when editing the registry, right-clicking, and reinstalling Python hadn't. Thanks to @Fantasizer for the hint.